# Get the string "System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection" from a Type (System.type) containing a generic ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I got a Type whose FullName is (if this helps) :

```
"System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"
```

From that Type, I'd like to get `"System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection"` as a string but I'd like to do it "cleanly", which means, without spliting the string with the char `` '`' ``.
I think the strategy is to get something like a Type or something else whose FullName will be `"System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection"` but I really don't manage to do it :/

Comment: There is no type named `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection` at the IL level after compilation it's name **is** `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection\`1` and `System.Type` represents a type as visible at the IL level, not how a specific language (C# in this case) represent it. And even for C# it's named `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<>` when the type is open (no type parameter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "real" type name is not `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`, it's `` System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1 ``, as VirtualBlackFox correctly mentions (because it's a generic type, `` `1 `` indicates the number of generic parameters).

You can get quite close by using `type.Name` (gives `` ObservableCollection`1 ``) and `type.Namespace` (gives `System.Collections.ObjectModel`).

Not that your type is most probably not the generic type, but its specification with generic parameter = `string`.

You can get the parameter type(s) (`string` in your case) by using [`type.GetGenericArguments()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx).

Comment: SO considering \` as a special character is really annoying on such questions isn't it ?

Comment: @VirtualBlackFox: yes, but I've just found a solution [here](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code): using double backticks :-P

Comment: nice I used the html code block and backtick char code but double backticks is cleaner (If not really more readable). Also added an answer with the point in spec defining it.

Comment: @VirtualBlackFox: I tried html `&#x60;`, but it seems to fail inside "inline" backtick'ed code.

Comment: yes need to use the html `<code>` tag directly for char codes to work : `&#96;` versus <code>&#96;</code> (But it doesn't work in comments as even filtered html is prohibited)

Comment: @VirtualBlackFox: nice, I didn't know about `<code>` -- thanks!

Comment: ok I can't avoid some string parsing, that was the main point of my question in the end :) I was using type.GetGenericArguments()[0], that works fine !

Comment: @Guillaume: with reflection, almost everything is possible. :) Anyway, the type canonical name _is_ ``ObservableCollection`1`` (`ObservableCollection`) would be a different, non-generic type), so maybe you can live with the backtick and don't need any parsing at all?

Answer (score 2):

*Just to complement Vlad's answer don't accept mine.*

The `` ` `` character is specified in the CLI ([ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm)) spec directly so it's safe and "clean" to parse it (As long as your C# code run under the CLI infrastructure) :

**10.7.2** :

> CLS-compliant generic type names are encoded using the format
>   `` "name[`arity]" `` , where […] indicates that the  grave
>   accent character `` "`" `` and arity together are optional.
>   The encoded name shall follow these rules:
>
> 1. name shall be an ID (see Partition II) that does not contain the `` "`" `` character.
> 2. arity is specified as an unsigned decimal number without leading zeros or spaces.
> 3. For a normal generic type, arity is the number of type parameters declared on the type.
> 4. For a nested generic type, arity is the number of newly introduced type parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the specs reference! It's always good to know the complete story.